# Reselect faces that was already selected?

Tags: python

How can I reselect faces that is already selected? I need to get selected faces, do something else, and then reselect those faces again. I tried this ,but it doesn't work.

```
import bpy


OBJ = bpy.context.edit_object
DATA = OBJ.data
FACES = DATA.polygons

#Get selected faces
FACES = [f for f in FACES if f.select]

#Deselect to see if selection works.
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#Select faces again
for S_FACES in FACES: 
    S_FACES.select = True
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use bmesh:

```
import bpy
import bmesh


OBJ = bpy.context.edit_object
DATA = OBJ.data
BM = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(DATA)

#Get selected faces
FACES = [f for f in BM.faces if f.select]

#Deselect to see if selection works.
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#Select faces again
for S_FACES in FACES:
    S_FACES.select = True

#updates viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(DATA, True)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally assign the vertices of the face in a vertex group, and the i click on "select", but i don't think is what you need[image]

Comment: Well, I guess that is one way I could do it. Not sure why my code doesn't work though. This "FACE = [f for f in FACES if f.select]" will get the selected faces ,but after deselecting it looses it.